# If a create a linux service this way, how can I see the stdout of my process?

Tags: linux, service

I've written a long running program. To make sure it runs on my server, I followed [this site's instructions](https://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/) for creating a service. Specifically the "Debian and Ubuntu (sysvinit)" approach using their example file that goes in `/etc/init.d/`.

The example file contains the following (I updated the variables at the top to match my scenario):

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          exampledaemon
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example
# Description:       Example start-stop-daemon - Debian
### END INIT INFO

NAME="my-service"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
APPDIR="/home/svc-user"
APPBIN="/home/svc-user/my-binary"
APPARGS=""
USER="svc-user"
GROUP="svc-user"

# Include functions 
set -e
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

start() {
  printf "Starting '$NAME'... "
  start-stop-daemon --start --chuid "$USER:$GROUP" --background --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid --chdir "$APPDIR" --exec "$APPBIN" -- $APPARGS || true
  printf "done\n"
}

#We need this function to ensure the whole process tree will be killed
killtree() {
    local _pid=$1
    local _sig=${2-TERM}
    for _child in $(ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid ${_pid}); do
        killtree ${_child} ${_sig}
    done
    kill -${_sig} ${_pid}
}

stop() {
  printf "Stopping '$NAME'... "
  [ -z `cat /var/run/$NAME.pid 2>/dev/null` ] || \
  while test -d /proc/$(cat /var/run/$NAME.pid); do
    killtree $(cat /var/run/$NAME.pid) 15
    sleep 0.5
  done 
  [ -z `cat /var/run/$NAME.pid 2>/dev/null` ] || rm /var/run/$NAME.pid
  printf "done\n"
}

status() {
  status_of_proc -p /var/run/$NAME.pid "" $NAME && exit 0 || exit $?
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|status}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I followed the rest of the steps from the site and have the service running. `top` shows it's running and using the expected amount of resources. When I run `service my-service status` I see the output produced by the downloaded script but nothing from my binary. I'm new to administrating linux servers so I'm unfamiliar with what exactly is going on here. The man page for `start-stop-daemon` doesn't mention anything about logs.

I could (and probably will) update my service to write logs to a file instead of stdout but I don't want to miss out on this learning opportunity.

What happens to the stdout of my service and if I can, how can I access it?

Comment: Don't use the old style sysvinit scripts on currently supported Debian or Ubuntu distributions. These are for obsolete distributions only. Use a systemd unit instead.

Comment: Is that when `journalctl` would come into play? Would it keep track of the logs? I have so much to learn in this space.

Comment: Yes, by default the standard output and error would go to the journal, (and from there to the syslog if you run a syslog daemon) though systemd also lets you redirect them.

Comment: Finished migrating the service. This is exactly what I want and seems a lot easier.